# Untar filenames in a character encoding different from encoding used in the filesystem

Tags: filenames, tar, character-encoding, unicode

I occasionally get tarballs where the filenames are encoded in ISO-8859-1 or some other pre-Unicode scheme.  My system uses UTF-8, so when I untar these archives with the usual options (`tar xvf foo.tar`) I end up with a directory full of mojibake filenames.

Until now I've been using [`convmv`](https://www.j3e.de/linux/convmv/) to convert the filenames to UTF-8 *after* they've been extracted.  This is a bit incovenient, because I either need to invoke `convmv` on each affected file, or else untar the file into a new directory, run `convmv` on the entire directory, and then move the files to where I wanted them originally.  Short of coding this functionality into a shell script, is there some way of converting the archived filenames to UTF-8 on the fly, as they are being untarred?

Answer (score 13):

Here is a little `tar` file extractor that modifies the names in memory before extracting:

```
#!/usr/bin/python27

import tarfile

def transform(data):
    u = data.decode('latin1')
    return u.encode('utf8')

tar = tarfile.open('archive.tar')
for m in tar.getmembers():
    m.name = transform(m.name)

tar.extractall()
```

**Warning:** unlike GNU `tar`, this extractor is not stripping leading `/`. Either add checking logic to this extractor or check each `tar` file before extracting with `tar -t`.

Comment: This is OK as long as you don't need to pass any additional options to `tar`.  I don't suppose there's any way of generalizing your solution so that it supports the same options as GNU tar…?

Comment: @Psychonaut Compression is handled by `tarfile` transparently. Options that handle on the fly manipulation (change UID, change paths) can be done in the same way as in the example. Filtering (extract only a subset) is also easy: create a list of all member, filter them, iterate over the list with `tar.extract()`. So it's all doable, just work. However, as GNU tar has tons of options, some of them *really* obscure, a full compatible version is not worth the effortd.

Answer (score 0):

[Thomas Erker's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/228285/34740) almost worked for me, except that the `getmembers` call seems to read the entire archive into memory, and the tar file I have is too big for that. So here is a modified version that reads one file at a time. The name transformation is also different, as in my tar file the file names show up with surrogate characters; I'm not sure if that will be generally applicable.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import tarfile
import sys
from pathlib import Path

def transform(data):
    try:
        data.encode('utf-8')
        return data
    except UnicodeEncodeError as err:
        u = data.encode('utf-8', 'surrogateescape')
        v = u.decode('latin-1')

        print(f'Replaced filename: {v}')
        v.encode('utf-8') # check that it can be encoded
        return v

tar = tarfile.open(sys.argv[1])
while (m := tar.next()) is not None:
    if m.name == '.':
        continue
    m.name = transform(m.name)
    path = Path(m.name)
    try:
        if path.stat().st_size == m.size:
            print(f'Already exists with the same size: skipping {m.name}')
            continue
        else:
            print(f'Size mismatch, extracting: {m.name}', flush=True)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f'About to extract {m.name}', flush=True)
    tar.extract(m)
    print(f'Extracted {m.name}')
```