# Combine the output of while loop into tar

Tags: centos, pipe, mysql

I'm trying to create a script that mysqldumps all my databases, creating an individual .sql file for each database and combines the output into backup-DATE.tar.gz.

I've gotten as far as being able to create the .sql backups, but the last hump I can't overcome due to my limited knowledge is how to combine all the .sql files into backup-DATE.tar.gz.

This is what I have so far:

```
mysql -N -u user -p'password' -e 'show databases' | while read dbname; do mysqldump --add-drop-table -u user -p'password' "$dbname" > /backuplocation/"$dbname".sql; done
```

This outputs all my databases into my backup location individually ie:

```
/backuplocation/
    /db1.sql
    /db2.sql
    /db3.sql
```

Is it possible to combine this output into backup-DATE.tar.gz with this strategy?

**Edited to better explain my goal:**

My goal is to run this script and get something like the following:

```
/backuplocation/
    /backup-DATE.tar.gz/
        /db1.sql
        /db2.sql
        /db3.sql
```

Instead of this:

```
/backuplocation/
    /db1.sql
    /db2.sql
    /db3.sql
```

Comment: You want to `tar` the files like `tar -f "backup-$(date).tar.gz" -cz /backuplocation/db[123].sql` or you want to `tar` the output instream [like this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/151057/52934)?

Comment: @mikeserv I edited the post to try to better explain my goal

Comment: I see the edit, but I assume that means the first thing then? You just want to put three files in a compressed `tar` archive, right? You `-c`reate an archive with `-c`, you specify the `-f`ile output w/ `-f` and you add files by name. If you use `pax` the process is very similar as well.

Comment: Yes, it would be the first thing.  I'm just not clear on how I would implement your first comment into my existing script

Comment: Well, not to be rude, but I'm probably more lost than you are on that score - I've never even seen your script.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your script so that it adds backup$(date) instead of the generic "backuplocation" (and first create a folder called backuplocation only once) then:

```
tar -czf backuplocation/backup-$(date).tar.gz backup$(date)
mv backup-$(date).tar.gz backuplocation/
rm -rf backup$(date)
```